# FPDF - How to change cell size in a foreach php

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, include, fpdf

http://phppot.com/php/generate-pdf-from-mysql-data-using-fpdf/
I use this code, but it doesn´t work.

```
    <?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
$result = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM toy");
$header = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='blog_samples' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='toy'");

require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);      
foreach($header as $heading) {
    foreach($heading as $column_heading)
        $pdf->Cell(90,12,$column_heading,1);
}
foreach($result as $row) {
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);   
    $pdf->Ln();
    foreach($row as $column)
        $pdf->Cell(90,12,$column,1);
}
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

i wanted to change the foreach command, i want to check the mysql, and when the $header is 'fun', i want the cell a little bit smaller than the other ones.

I try it with if, but it doesn´t work
Please help!

Comment: *...i want the cell a little bit smaller than the other ones.* what do you mean by cell size? Do you want to decrease the height of the cell or the width of the cell? Or both?

Comment: And how much it should be?

Comment: the cells! with header 'fun' should be 45, not 90

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To decrease the width of the cell as per your condition, you can do something like this:

```
// your code

foreach($header as $heading){
    foreach($heading as $column_heading){
        if($column_heading == "fun"){
            $pdf->Cell(45,12,$column_heading,1);
        }else{
            $pdf->Cell(90,12,$column_heading,1);
        }
    }
}

// your code
```

**Edited:**

```
// your code

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12); 
foreach($header as $heading){
    $counter = 1;
    foreach($heading as $column_heading){
        if($counter > 3){
             $pdf->Cell(45,12,$column_heading,1);
        }else{
             $pdf->Cell(90,12,$column_heading,1);
        }
        ++$counter;
    }
}

foreach($result as $row){
    $counter = 1;
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);   
    $pdf->Ln();
    foreach($row as $column){
        if($counter > 3){
            $pdf->Cell(45,12,$column,1);
        }else{
            $pdf->Cell(90,12,$column,1);
        }
        ++$counter;
    }
}
$pdf->Output();
```

Here's the reference:

- [FPDF `Cell` documentation](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/cell.htm)

Comment: I want to decrease the full column; the header and all cells in the column!

Comment: @J.Doe What do you mean by *full column, the header and all cells in the column*. Please provide a screenshot of your PDF.

Comment: @J.Doe And I think in the question you meant *when the $column_heading is 'fun', i want the...*, because `$header` is an array and you can't compare an array with a string `'fun'`.

Comment: I can't see any screenshot there, the link is broken. I've recreated your issue on my local system. [Here's the screenshot](http://prntscr.com/9k9z7p). Now tell me where do you want to make changes?

Comment: i have 3 columns, and the third column should be smaller than the other ones. it´s only an example

Comment: @J.Doe Well then [upload your screenshot](http://prnt.sc/) and copy-paste the screenshot link here.

Comment: @J.Doe So you have 5 columns and you want last 2 columns to be small, right?

Comment: @J.Doe I've updated my answer again. I forgot to include the updated column headings. Please see the **edited** section of my answer. Now it should work fine.